# input text box no cursor in popover safari

Tags: html, angular, input, safari

Unable to type text/place cursor in popover in angular application for safari, IE and Chrome work.

[Inside popup for safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q06Xq.png)

[chrome popup text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wErbg.png)

```html
<div *ngIf="placeMarkService.currentPopOverfeature != undefined">
      <input class="form-control margin-bottom-5 no-margin" style="font-size: 10px; height: 24px;" #placeName
             [ngModel]="placeMarkService.currentPopOverfeature.get('name')">
    </div>
        <div
      *ngIf="placeMarkService.currentPopOverfeature != undefined">
      <textarea class="form-control no-margin" style=" height: 64px;" #placeDesc
                [ngModel]="placeMarkService.currentPopOverfeature.get('description')"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-webkit-user-select: text!important;